# PHP Login System with sessions cannot login

Tags: php, session, authentication

I am working on login system. But, i cannot log in. I have set my database table.

login.php

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    include_once("db.php");
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);

    $password = md5($password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $db_password = $row['password'];

    if($password == $db_password) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        header("Location: av_pocetna.html");
    } else {
        echo "You didn't enter the correct details!";
    }

}
 ?>
<html>
  <head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
 <body>
<h1 style="font-family: Tahoma;">Login</h1>
<form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text"  autofocus>
    <input placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
    <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and this is db.php

```
<? php

$db=mysqli_connect('192.168.1.113:8080','root','hidden','av');
?>
```

connent of users table
id
username
password

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
1
a
0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661

Comment: @Anant still doesn't work.

Comment: @Anant http://pastebin.com/qpiTjWjc here is what i get

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: db in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 8
 
Notice: Undefined variable: username in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 8
 
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 8

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: db in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 9
 
Notice: Undefined variable: password in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 9
 
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 9
 
Notice: Undefined variable: db in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 14
 
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 14

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 15

Comment: @Anant as i could see the error must do something with db.php

Comment: `$db=mysqli_connect('192.168.1.113:8080','root','hidden','av')or die(mysqli_connect_error());` change it and check db connection established or not?

Comment: i keep getting the same Notices and Warnings

Comment: i don't understand you? do you meen to show you the errors that i got or?

Comment: Did you include or require your db.php file ? I can't see where the db.php file is injected into the page

Comment: @talk2toyin It's there `include_once("db.php");`

Comment: yes @Anant it is included

Comment: What should i do with db connection

Comment: @AleksandarIvanovski remove all this unnecessary comments of yours regarding errors and other. Make the page clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `form code` look right. Just change like below your `login.php` code:-

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    $conn = mysqli_connect('host-name','user-name','password','database-name');
    if($conn){
        if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);
            $password = md5($password);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            if($query){
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                $id = $row['id'];
                $db_password = $row['password'];
                if($password == $db_password) {
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                    header("Location: av_pocetna.html");
                } else {
                    echo "You didn't enter the correct details!";
                }
            }else{
                echo "query not executed because".mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "db connection error".mysqli_connect_error();
    }
 ?>
```

Note:- i have added connection code here only,so change the credentials there. And use this same code to check working or not?

**Also if you are working on your local then  change `ip address` to `localhost` and check. If it will work then it will work with `include("db.php")` too.I mean to say try with `$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','aleksandar','av');`**

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.113' (111) in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 5
db connection errorCan't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.113' (111) does that mean that it cannot connect to the mysql server???

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: db in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: db in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 11

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: db in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 14

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 14
query not executed because

Comment: What should i declare for $db?  $dv="av" or something else

Comment: @AleksandarIvanovski REMOVE ALL THE ABOVE  COMMENTS OF YOURS  AS YOU GOT THE SOLUTION.

Answer (score 0):

Oh Okay.
Lets try debugging one step at a time then.
In your db.php file, use this:

```
   // Connecting to mysql database
    $db = new mysqli('192.168.1.113:8080','root','hidden','av');

    // Check for database connection error
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
```

If you get any error, please dump it here for debugging.

Updated.

```
    // Connecting to mysql database
    $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','hidden','av');

    // Check for database connection error
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
```

Comment: I don't get errors while connecting, so as i can understand there is not problem with the connection

Comment: Ok then! In your login.php, wrap your codes in a try catch block and just dump the error in the catch block

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know what is try catch block

Comment: Sorry! This error: Notice: Undefined variable: db in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 9 Notice: Undefined variable: password in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 9 Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/html/natprevar_3/login.php on line 9 Notice: Undefined variable: db in ... states your $db variable in login.php file is undefined. I would suggest declaring the $db variable as a global variable before including or requiring the db.php

Comment: so sould i set $db="av"

Comment: Okay! after these lines: // Check for database connection error
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    } do a var_dump($db); lets see what you get.

Comment: Also, why are you not using 'localhost' as your db connect host instead of '192.168.1.113:8080' ? Better yet, try removing the port section so it becomes $db = new mysqli('192.168.1.113','root','hidden','av'); or $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','hidden','av');

Comment: i switched to localhost

Comment: What solution helped ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working login.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','aleksandar','av');
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','aleksandar','av');
if($conn){
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);
        $password = md5($password);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        if($query){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            $id = $row['id'];
            $db_password = $row['password'];
            if($password == $db_password) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                header("Location: av_pocetna.html");
            } else {
                echo "You didn't enter the correct details!";
            }
        }else{
            echo "query not executed because".mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "db connection error".mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
<html>
 <head>
<title>Login</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h1 style="font-family: Tahoma;">Login</h1>
        <form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text"      autofocus>
      <input placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
     <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you ok, two time db connection creation? why?

Comment: Also what's the difference in my code and your code instead of unnecessarily creating two db connection in your code.